# Redirect from specific page to external website

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a link with a query string that I need to redirect to an external website using .htaccess

for example:

```
 http://check.local.com/mod/ctxcatalog/course.php?id=187
```

to

```
https://google.com
```

I have tried everything with mod rewrite and 301 redirects.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you show the "everything" that you have tried?

Comment: You've set up the condition but you're not actually performing the rewrite there (since it's commented out).

Comment: Just for testing purpose i commented the code.@CD001

Comment: Works on my dev box... I'm assuming you've got the .htaccess file in the right location? For this it would have to be at the document root.

Comment: It should be `ewriteRule ^mod/ctxcatalog/course\.php$ https://google.com/? [L,R=301,NC]` to remove query string.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a specific page ,you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://Google.com/ [NC,L,R]
```

The rule above will redirect `http://example.com/page.php` to `http://example.com/` including any querystrings from the old uri to the new one. ie: `/page.php?querystring` => `http://example.com/?querystring` .

If you want to redirect a specific page with a specific query perameter, you can use the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://example.com/? [L,R]
```

This will redirect `/page.php?id=123` to `http://example.com/` and it does not append the old querystring `id=123` to the destination url `http://example.com/` as we have discarded them using the `?` in Rule's target url http://example.com/ `?` .